# How to load jstree with closed checked node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I set `selected: true`

```
$('#tree3').jstree({ 'core' : {
  'data' : [
    { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node" , state : {opened : false}},
    { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 3" , state : {opened : false, selected: true}, icon: false},
    { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" , state : {opened : false, selected: true}, icon: false}
  ]
},
  "checkbox" : {
    "keep_selected_style" : false
  },
  "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
});
```

[image: IMAGE: I get bad result]

Why was opened my node?

If I try `selected: false` I get closed node, but doesn't checked.

jsTree - v3.2.1 and older

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all nodes are not open but are revealed on startup. Using expand_selected_onload as below, you should be able to load the tree in an unopened state:

```
$('#tree3').jstree({ 'core' : {
  'data' : [
    { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node" , state : {opened : false}},
    { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 3" , state : {opened : false, selected: true}, icon: false},
    { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" , state : {opened : false, selected: true}, icon: false}
  ],
  expand_selected_onload : false
},
  "checkbox" : {
    "keep_selected_style" : false
  },
  "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
});
```

Comment: It's weird that they do not seem to open on load if the nodes are not being checked (or used in an other way). Great solution though!